# NoSuchAlgorithmException: MessageDigest SHA implementation not found while ObjectInputStream.readObject() Android

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm saving the model classes in the local storage for caching purpose

I using following for writing the Object to the File

```
private void writeData(Object data, String fileName) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(data);
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and following is the code for reading the object from file

```
public Object readData(String fileName) {
    Object data = null;
    if (context != null) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            data = is.readObject();
            is.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

It works well, but in some devices It throws strange exception ie

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MessageDigest SHA implementation not found
```

I don't know what happening in the background, how the readData throws the NoSuchAlogorithmException, I didn't used any MessageDigest in this. and I searched lot about ObjectInputStream.readObject() in Java and Android documentation. I didn't get any solution.

I tried to put catch class for `NoSuchAlgorithmException`, but in eclipse its shows as error

```
Unreachable catch block for NoSuchAlgorithmException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body
```

Here I attache the complete crash Log

```
java.lang.Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MessageDigest SHA implement    ation not found
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:420)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.cre    ateClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:259)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.verifyAndInit(ObjectInputStream.java:2375)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1662)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:683)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1803)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:657)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeN    ative(N    ative Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
at com.test.util.CacheManager.readD    ata(CacheManager.java:104)
at com.test.SplashActivity.onCre    ate(SplashActivity.java:178)
at android.app.Activity.performCre    ate(Activity.java:5206)
at android.app.Instrument    ation.callActivityOnCre    ate(Instrument    ation.java:1083)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
at android.os.Handler.disp    atchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeN    ative(N    ative Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.N    ativeStart.main(N    ative Method)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MessageDigest SHA implement    ation not found
at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:91)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:418)
... 42 more
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MessageDigest SHA implement    ation not found
at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:91)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:418)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.cre    ateClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:259)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.verifyAndInit(ObjectInputStream.java:2375)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1662)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:683)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1803)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:657)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeN    ative(N    ative Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
at com.test.util.CacheManager.readD    ata(CacheManager.java:104)
at com.test.SplashActivity.onCre    ate(SplashActivity.java:178)
at android.app.Activity.performCre    ate(Activity.java:5206)
at android.app.Instrument    ation.callActivityOnCre    ate(Instrument    ation.java:1083)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
at android.os.Handler.disp    atchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeN    ative(N    ative Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.N    ativeStart.main(N    ative Method)
```

**EDIT**

Here is the Class I tried to write and read it. inner class I used AutoPromoData, OrderBkgPixData SubscriptionUrlData, etc are inside this class contains simple int and string for index and url.

**Configuration.jvaa**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.test.model.CacheTimeData;
import com.test.SplashUrlData;
import com.test.SubscriptionUrlData;

public class Configuration {

    int version;

    @SerializedName("pivotCodeRetour")
    int pivotCodeRetour;

    ArrayList<WSTimeOutData> WSTimeOut;
    ArrayList<AutoPromoData> AutoPromo;
    ArrayList<StreetMktData> StressMkt;
    ArrayList<OrderBkgPixData> OrderBkgPix;
    ArrayList<LogBkgPixData> LogBkgPix;
    ArrayList<SubscriptionUrlData> SubscriptionBkgPix;

    String Voucher;
    ArrayList<PhoneContactData> PhoneContact;
    String ProdAvailability;
    String PaymentUrl;
    String TravSaleHomeUrl;
    String TravCartUrl;
    String TravOrderDetailUrl;
    String TicketSaleHomeUrl;
    String TicketOrderUrl;
    String CGV;
    String wishlist;

    int pushCart;
    int pushVoucher;

    ArrayList<SplashUrlData> Splashscreen;
    ArrayList<CacheTimeData> CacheTime;

    public int getPushCart() {
        return pushCart;
    }

    public ArrayList<SubscriptionUrlData> getSubscriptionBkgPix() {
        return SubscriptionBkgPix;
    }

    public void setSubscriptionBkgPix(
            ArrayList<SubscriptionUrlData> subscriptionBkgPix) {
        SubscriptionBkgPix = subscriptionBkgPix;
    }

    public void setPushCart(int pushCart) {
        this.pushCart = pushCart;
    }

    public int getPushVoucher() {
        return pushVoucher;
    }

    public void setPushVoucher(int pushVoucher) {
        this.pushVoucher = pushVoucher;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public ArrayList<WSTimeOutData> getWSTimeOut() {
        return WSTimeOut;
    }

    public void setWSTimeOut(ArrayList<WSTimeOutData> wSTimeOut) {

        WSTimeOut = wSTimeOut;
    }

    public ArrayList<AutoPromoData> getAutoPromo() {
        return AutoPromo;
    }

    public void setAutoPromo(ArrayList<AutoPromoData> autoPromo) {
        AutoPromo = autoPromo;
    }

    public ArrayList<StreetMktData> getStressMkt() {
        return StressMkt;
    }

    public void setStressMkt(ArrayList<StreetMktData> stressMkt) {
        StressMkt = stressMkt;
    }

    public ArrayList<OrderBkgPixData> getOrderBkgPix() {
        return OrderBkgPix;
    }

    public void setOrderBkgPix(ArrayList<OrderBkgPixData> orderBkgPix) {
        OrderBkgPix = orderBkgPix;
    }

    public ArrayList<LogBkgPixData> getLogBkgPix() {
        return LogBkgPix;
    }

    public void setLogBkgPix(ArrayList<LogBkgPixData> logBkgPix) {
        LogBkgPix = logBkgPix;
    }

    public String getVoucher() {
        return Voucher;
    }

    public void setVoucher(String voucher) {
        Voucher = voucher;
    }

    public ArrayList<PhoneContactData> getPhoneContact() {
        return PhoneContact;
    }

    public void setPhoneContact(ArrayList<PhoneContactData> phoneContact) {
        PhoneContact = phoneContact;
    }

    public String getProdAvailability() {
        return ProdAvailability;
    }

    public void setProdAvailability(String prodAvailability) {
        ProdAvailability = prodAvailability;
    }

    public String getPaymentUrl() {
        return PaymentUrl;
    }

    public void setPaymentUrl(String paymentUrl) {
        PaymentUrl = paymentUrl;
    }

    public String getTravSaleHomeUrl() {
        return TravSaleHomeUrl;
    }

    public void setTravSaleHomeUrl(String travSaleHomeUrl) {
        TravSaleHomeUrl = travSaleHomeUrl;
    }

    public String getTravCartUrl() {
        return TravCartUrl;
    }

    public void setTravCartUrl(String travCartUrl) {
        TravCartUrl = travCartUrl;
    }

    public String getTravOrderDetailUrl() {
        return TravOrderDetailUrl;
    }

    public void setTravOrderDetailUrl(String travOrderDetailUrl) {
        TravOrderDetailUrl = travOrderDetailUrl;
    }

    public String getTicketSaleHomeUrl() {
        return TicketSaleHomeUrl;
    }

    public void setTicketSaleHomeUrl(String ticketSaleHomeUrl) {
        TicketSaleHomeUrl = ticketSaleHomeUrl;
    }

    public String getTicketOrderUrl() {
        return TicketOrderUrl;
    }

    public void setTicketOrderUrl(String ticketOrderUrl) {
        TicketOrderUrl = ticketOrderUrl;
    }

    public ArrayList<SplashUrlData> getSplashscreen() {
        return Splashscreen;
    }

    public void setSplashscreen(ArrayList<SplashUrlData> splashscreen) {
        Splashscreen = splashscreen;
    }

    public ArrayList<CacheTimeData> getCacheTime() {
        return CacheTime;
    }

    public void setCacheTime(ArrayList<CacheTimeData> cacheTime) {
        CacheTime = cacheTime;
    }

    public int getPivotCodeRetour() {
        return pivotCodeRetour;
    }

    public void setPivotCodeRetour(int pivotCodeRetour) {
        this.pivotCodeRetour = pivotCodeRetour;
    }

    public String getCGV() {
        return CGV;
    }

    public void setCGV(String cGV) {
        CGV = cGV;
    }

    public String getWishlist() {
        return wishlist;
    }

    public void setWishlist(String wishlist) {
        this.wishlist = wishlist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code of object that you are trying to write/to read.

Comment: @SergeyGlotov sorry it was a private project, I can't share the data, The class is simple model with integers and strings only

Comment: ok, I'm going to close the question. Problem should be there.

Comment: problem should be where? If you don't know the solutions, let other do

Comment: Problem should be in the class that you are trying to write/to read. I think nobody can answer the question in the current state. I can say only one thing now: there is no `SHA` algorithm http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest

Comment: @SergeyGlotov I edited my question with the class I used.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug report against the devices concerned, but you can avoid it by always defining your own serialVersionUID in your Serializable classes, which you should be doing anyway for other reasons. It's happening when Java goes to create a default value for this missing class attribute.